# MySql Index working differently in range scan

Tags: mysql, indexing

```
select * from [Table] where [DateColumn] >= [dateValue1] and [DateColumn] <= [dateValue2];
```

Indexing is not happening

```
select * from [Table] where [DateColumn] > [dateValue1] and [DateColumn] < [dateValue2];
```

Indexing is happening.

The Date Column is indexed

Can anyone please clarify why this difference occurs.

Query

```
select * from test_index where test_date >= '2016-11-15' and test_date <= '2016-12-02';
```

Explain

```
   +----+-------------+------------+------------+------+-------------------------------------------------+------+---------+------+-------+----------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table      | partitions | type | possible_keys                                   | key  | key_len | ref  | rows  | filtered | Extra       |
+----+-------------+------------+------------+------+-------------------------------------------------+------+---------+------+-------+----------+----]---------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | test_index | NULL       | ALL  | idx_negativebalance_firstnegativeoccurrencedate | NULL | NULL    | NULL | 16899 |    17.92 | Using where |
+----+-------------+------------+------------+------+-------------------------------------------------+------+---------+------+-------+----------+-------------+
```

Query 2

select * from test_index where test_date > '2016-11-15' and test_date < '2016-12-02';

```
+----+-------------+------------+------------+-------+-------------------------------------------------+-------------------------------------------------+---------+------+------+----------+-----------------------+
| id | select_type | table      | partitions | type  | possible_keys                                   | key   | key_len | ref  | rows | filtered | Extra                 |
+----+-------------+------------+------------+-------+-------------------------------------------------+-------------------------------------------------+---------+------+------+----------+-----------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | test_index | NULL       | range | idx_negativebalance_firstnegativeoccurrencedate | idx_negativebalance_firstnegativeoccurrencedate | 8       | NULL | 2727 |   100.00 | Using index condition |
+----+-------------+------------+------------+-------+-------------------------------------------------+-------------------------------------------------+---------+------+------+----------+-----------------------+
```

Comment: The two datevalues are different, right?

Comment: I have edited the question @Strawberry ,  I think it ll be more clear now..

Comment: And the EXPLAIN?

Comment: for the first query full table scan but the second query is going for index based scan.

Comment: Oh, come on. Share.

Comment: @Strawberry I have updated the details.

Comment: OK, fact is, I don't the answer :-(. Out of curiousity, what happens if you use `select * from [Table] where [DateColumn] > [dateValue1 - interval 1 day] and [DateColumn] < [dateValue2] + interval 1 day;`

Comment: I have already tried that.. this type of query is using index

Comment: How fast does each run?

Answer (score 2):

In my quick test, I can see that the index is ignored if 85% of results fall within the range. Is it possible that you're just on the edge of the 85% figure?

[dense is a column of a little over a million numbers ranging from 1-100, and with an approximately equal distribution across the board]

```
mysql> EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE dense >= 84 AND dense <= 100;
+----+-------------+----------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+---------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table    | type | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref  | rows    | Extra       |
+----+-------------+----------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+---------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | my_table | ALL  | dense         | NULL | NULL    | NULL | 1048576 | Using where |
+----+-------------+----------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+---------+-------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE dense >= 85 AND dense <= 100;
+----+-------------+----------+-------+---------------+-------+---------+------+--------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table    | type  | possible_keys | key   | key_len | ref  | rows   | Extra       |
+----+-------------+----------+-------+---------------+-------+---------+------+--------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | my_table | range | dense         | dense | 4       | NULL | 168389 | Using where |
+----+-------------+----------+-------+---------------+-------+---------+------+--------+-------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: The Optimizer has no hard-coded 85%, but the principle is correct.

Comment: @RickJames But it doesn't really explain why `x > [dateValue1 - interval 1 day] and x < [dateValue2] + interval 1 day;` *does* use an index, does it?

Comment: Change the dates to be closer together or farther apart; see what happens.

Comment: There is a cutoff, but it is dependent on the phase of the moon (or so it seems).  Changing the dates will show that the optimizer is willing to do it either way.  (If not, I will be surprised, and I will dig further.)